# How would I use grep to get only the Hondas?

Tags: shell, command-line

I used `grep -A 4 L337 vehicles | grep -C 2 Blue | grep -B 4 6` to get these outputs but now I also need to filter it so it returns the outputs with the make Honda as well.

```
License Plate L337QE9
Make: Honda
Color: Blue
Owner: Erika Owens
Height: 6'5"
--
License Plate L337GB9
Make: Toyota
Color: Blue
Owner: Matt Waite
Height: 6'1"
--
License Plate L337OI9
Make: Jaguar
Color: Blue
Owner: Brian Boyer
Height: 6'6"
--
License Plate L337X19
Make: Fiat
Color: Blue
Owner: Al Shaw
Height: 6'5"
--
License Plate L3373U9
Make: Ford
Color: Blue
Owner: Miranda Mulligan
Height: 6'6"
--
--
--
License Plate L337369
--
License Plate L337DV9
Make: Honda
Color: Blue
Owner: Joe Germuska
Height: 6'2"
--
License Plate L3375A9
Make: Honda
Color: Blue
Owner: Jeremy Bowers
Height: 6'1"
--
License Plate L337WR9
Make: Honda
Color: Blue
Owner: Jacqui Maher
Height: 6'2"
```

Comment: Use `awk` with `RS=-`

Comment: Please show the first 10 lines of the file *vehicles*.

Answer (score 1):

For the search append this to the existing pipeline:

```
| grep -A 3 -B 1 "Make: Honda"
```

---

Also, in your preliminary code replace this:

```
 | grep -B 4 6
```

with this:

```
 | grep -B 4 "^Height: [678912]'"
```

Otherwise, `grep` will obediently return License Plates with *"6"* too.  Also searching for just a *"6"* would fail to list a 7 foot Honda -- searching for `[678912]` gives a range from *6'1"* to *29'11"*, (should be OK, unless there are Hondas more than 30 feet high, or less than 2 feet tall).

For similar reasons it's safest to use field names for every `grep`.

The total code would look like this:

```
grep -A 4 "^License Plate L337" vehicles | 
grep -C 2 "^Color: Blue" |
grep -B 4 "^Height: [678912]'" |
grep -A 3 -B 1 "^Make: Honda"
```

Comment: This is extremely brittle compared to the Awk solution, though.

Answer (score -1):

You can probably get away with `awk '/Honda/' RS=-`

It would almost certainly be better to replace your prior `grep` pipeline with a single `awk`.  Perhaps just

```
awk '/Honda/ && /L337/ && /Blue/' RS=- ORS=-- vehicles
```

Some versions of awk allow RS to be more than one character, so you might like `RS=--`, but the results are unspecified and it's not really necessary in this case.

To filter out records for which height > 6, you could do:

```
awk '/Honda/ && /L337/ && /Blue/ && ($NF + 0) >= 6' RS=- ORS=-- vehicles
```

It's a bit fragile, since it relies on the value of the height being the last record (I don't see any guarantee that the records are always listed in the same order), but it's certainly better than just `grep`ing for a `6` (which would miss vehicles of height 7'0" or greater.)

Comment: This leaves out the filter for cars over six feet tall.

Comment: @agc There's no filter for cars over 6 feet tall, there's only a filter for records that contain a `6`.  To add a filter that compares numbers is much simpler with `awk` than with `grep`, though.

Comment: For the OP's intent, see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69302588/how-would-i-use-grep-to-get-only-the-hondas/69304964?noredirect=1#comment122489961_69302624).

Comment: This code assumes the *vehicles* record separator is '--', but the OP never shows *vehicles*, just the output of `grep`.  But it's probably `grep` itself that outputs '--' when using context line control, try this for an example:  `seq 30 | grep -A 0 3`.

Comment: @agc Yes, that is a good point.  It would be convenient to see the original input file.  In any case, a string of `grep`s is *not* the correct way to solve this problem.

Comment: Well `grep` isn't the *best* way, but it works and answers the OP's question.  Having a `grep` answer permits doubting students to compare both `awk` and `grep` answers -- all the better to show the merits of `awk`.